# Cannot run test API call using Jest / mongodb-memory-server (problem setimeout)

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I did test many functions in my app using jest / mongodb-memory-server and they all works great. But but some reason I cannot run API call test.

Every time I'm trying to run a api call I have a setimout problem and even if I increase it it still does not work. My functions just return a list of users... no more.

```js
 FAIL  Tests/Controller/auth.test.js (11.991 s)
  ● Console

    console.warn
      Using NodeJS below 12.22.0

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:21:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:13:1)

  ● test updateSchemaField() › get users list

    MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

      10 |     useUnifiedTopology: true,
      11 |   };
    > 12 |   await mongoose.connect(uri, mongooseOpts);
         |                  ^
      13 | };
      14 |
      15 | module.exports.closeDatabase = async () => {

      at NativeConnection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.openUri (node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:697:13)
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:330:10
      at node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
      at promiseOrCallback (node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
      at Mongoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1151:10)
      at Mongoose.connect (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:329:20)
      at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports.connect (Tests/db.js:12:18)
      at Tests/Controller/auth.test.js:5:23

  ● test updateSchemaField() › get users list

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

       5 | beforeAll(async () => await db.connect());
       6 |
    >  7 | afterEach(async () => await db.clearDatabase());
         | ^
       8 |
       9 | afterAll(async () => await db.closeDatabase());
      10 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (Tests/Controller/auth.test.js:7:1)


  ● Test suite failed to run

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

       7 | afterEach(async () => await db.clearDatabase());
       8 |
    >  9 | afterAll(async () => await db.closeDatabase());
         | ^
      10 |
      11 | describe("test updateSchemaField()", (done) => {
      12 |   it("get users list", async () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (Tests/Controller/auth.test.js:9:1)

 PASS  Tests/Data/schemaCRUD.test.js
  ● Console

    console.warn
      Using NodeJS below 12.22.0

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/util/MongoInstance.ts:21:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:13:1)

 PASS  Tests/Utils/user.test.js

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       1 failed, 9 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.859 s, estimated 13 s
Ran all test suites matching /.\/Tests/i.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

The test

```js
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../../app");
const db = require("../db");

beforeAll(async () => await db.connect());

afterEach(async () => await db.clearDatabase());

afterAll(async () => await db.closeDatabase());

describe("test updateSchemaField()", () => {
  it("get users list", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get("/api/auth/test");
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is trying to connect with multiple URI. You are establishing a database connection in the test file is fine but there is also another database connection call with different URI in app.js .

Comment: Yes but I don't get why I don't have this problem in my other test file (which I have a mongodb-memory-server connection too with a similar structure) ?

Comment: Can you run only test case which is failing and check results.

Comment: The result was the same. To make it work I don't know why but I have to stop my docker and then it works.. I don't get why because mongodb-memory-server is not suppose to run the "real" database that I have in my app.js